# Insert and update system time using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using a trigger for auto increment "slno", "Cust_Id". Now i need to create a **insert trigger** for inserting system date for the field **Created_Date** and **Submitted_Date**. And need a **update trigger** for only **Submitted_date** (Need to update the current system time on update).

Now i am using this trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON customer_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customer_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.Created_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from customer_details), 0) + 1;
  SET NEW.Cust_id = CONCAT('CUST', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This works fine for insert and i don't know how to put the update trigger for the "submitted date" inside this trigger.

Thanks
Acube.

Comment: you need to make a new trigger
    .....
    CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON customer_details
    ....

    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I am getting a error while adding a update trigger **#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'**

Comment: Try to run DROP TRIGGER <trigger name> before create the new triggers

Comment: Its working fine, i changed the trigger name and inserted the update trigger adding with the existing insert trigger. Thanks AlexF.

Comment: I have added another trigger with another name. This works for me.

    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON customer_details
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;

Thanks,
Acube.